# Using c# System.DateTime like c++ time_t

Tags: c#, datetime, time

In C++ I am able to get the current time when my application starts I can use

```
time_t appStartTime = time(null);
```

then to find the difference in seconds from when it started I can just do the same thing, then find the difference. It looks like I should be using "System.DateTime" in C# net, but the MSDN is confusing in its explanation.

How can I use System.DateTime to find the difference in time (in seconds) between when my application starts, and the current time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Now property

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

//work

DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
```

and then just simply calculate the difference.

```
currentTime - startTime;
```

If you would like to measure the performance consider using [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

```
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    //work

    stopWatch.Stop();
```

Answer (score 2):

As everyone suggested... But they were a little wrong :-) Use `DateTime.UtcNow`, because

- It's faster (`DateTime.Now` calls `DateTime.UtcNow`)
- It works around change of DST on/off.

OR

As @Shekhar_Pro suggested (yes, he was right!), use the Stopwatch

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
.... your code
sw.Stop();
var ms = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

or

```
var ticks = sw.ElapsedTicks;
```

Oh... and I was forgetting... What you are doing is probably worthless in certain situation... You know, 2011 processors are multicore (and even 2010 :-) )... If you app is vaguely multithread you are probably better measuring:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime
```

This include the use of all the cores used by your app... So on a dual core, using both cores, it will "gain" 2 seconds for every "real time" second.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this for checking performance and time taken to Execute code then you Best bet is to use [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

otherwise System.DateTime has a [Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx) function which can be used to get a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) object or even a simple `-` (subtract) operator will do it.
Then that TimeSpan object has a property of [TotalSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds.aspx) which you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to do this:

- Use DateTime.Now.  Subtracting produces a TimeSpan.  Takes 8 bytes of storage, times up to 8000 years, resolution of 1 millisecond but accurate to 1/64 second on most machines.
- Use Environment.TickCount.  Similar to time_t but relative from machine boot time.  Takes 4 bytes of storage, times up to 24 days (49 with a cast), resolution and accuracy same as DateTime.
- Use Stopwatch.  Stored on the heap, resolution is machine dependent but almost always well below a microsecond.  Accuracy isn't usually good but repeats decently, assume +/- 5%.  Best used to measure small intervals for comparison.
- Use timeGetTime.  This requires pinvoke to use this multimedia timer.  Similar to Environment.TickCount, you can get 1 msec accuracy by using timeBeginPeriod.  This is not cheap since it has system-wide effects.  Best avoided.

Keep in mind that process execution is subject to the vagaries of overall operating system load, your program is sharing resources with the other 70-odd processes that are running.  Either DateTime or TickCount has plenty of accuracy for that.

Comment: +1 for multiple different ways with explanations and pros and cons.  Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
//some code
TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now - startTime;
int seconds = difference.TotalSeconds.Truncate();
```